# How to access object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this object from a `JSON` file

```
{
    "Apple": "Red",
    "Orange": "Orange",
    "Guava": "Green",   
}
```

Then I converted it into `Object` using

```
var data = JSON.parse(dataFromJson);
```

then it will output `JavaScript object`

**Question**

Is it possible to access `"Apple", "Orange", "Guava"` then store it into `var fruits` then `"Red", "Orange","Green"` into `var Color`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do something like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(dataFromJson);

var fruits = [];
var colors = [];

for(var fruit in data) {
    fruits.push(fruit);
    colors.push(data[fruit]);
}
```

Comment: This associating is more elegant than mine :) thumbs up for that, have an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is several ways to do this, either iterate over the object and do it "manually"

```
for (var i = 0;i > data.length; i++) {
    colors.push(data[i]);
    fruits.push(Object.keys(data)[i]);
}
```

or let the Object methods do this for you.

```
var fruits = Object.keys(data);
var colors = Object.values(data);
```

Have some reading about the Object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

The    `Object.values()`   method is **EXPERIMENTAL** as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)